# Unable to enter text in WPF TextBox in F# FSI

Tags: wpf, f#

In the F# WPF code below, I am unable to enter any text in the text box when I 'show' the WPF window from the F# FSI. Is this something to do with Windows Forms Event loop being used?

```
let txtBox = new TextBox()
txtBox.BorderThickness <- Thickness(2.)
txtBox.Margin <- Thickness(7.)
txtBox.IsReadOnly <- false

let wnd = new Window(Title = "Test", Height = 500., Width = 500.)
wnd.Content <- txtBox
wnd.Show()
```

Based on the answer below by **John Palmer**, I have updated the code above with the correct version.
The code below now works correctly in F# FSI.

```
let txtBox = new TextBox()
txtBox.BorderThickness <- Thickness(2.)
txtBox.Margin <- Thickness(7.)
txtBox.IsReadOnly <- false

let wnd = new Window(Title = "Test", Height = 500., Width = 500.)
wnd.Content <- txtBox

(new Application()).Run(wnd) |> ignore
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to call `Application.Run` - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.run%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  This will start the event loop for you automatically.