# WPF TextBox/RichTextBox started from F# Interactive not accepting input

Tags: wpf, f#

Getting this weird issue, not sure if it's just me, and I don't remember this happening before...

```
#r "PresentationFramework"
#r "PresentationCore"
#r "WindowsBase"
System.Windows.Window(
    Content = System.Windows.Controls.TextBox())
    .Show()
```

The window shows up, the `TextBox` shows up, but I can't enter any alphanumeric text unless I paste them in, only spaces. Same deal with `RichTextBox`.

On the other hand, **it works just fine with `ShowDialog()`**, which led me to suspect it might have something to do with the event pump, so I [replaced fsi.EventLoop with a WPF one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723823/fsi-wpf-event-loop?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) -- but that one won't even call `Run()` for whatever reason.

Edit: The "answer" on the other question uses `Application.Run()`, which is effectively the same thing as using `ShowDialog()` in that both are blocking calls. However, this decimates the utility of calling WPF from FSI. My question is specifically on using the TextBox controls *without* making a blocking call to show the window.

Comment: The thread that would be process input events is blocked (it's waiting for text input in the shell). You could try launching the window in a separate thread)

Comment: @FuleSnabel I thought about that, but it captures spacebar, backspace, and everything else just fine. I can also hook onto `TextBox.KeyDown`, and sure enough, it's firing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to enter text in WPF TextBox in F# FSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20679125/unable-to-enter-text-in-wpf-textbox-in-f-fsi)

Comment: Gotta love this community's trigger-happy moderation. Vote to close perfectly in-line questions because it's a "duplicate" of a five year old question that never got fully answered and has a different requirement.

Comment: Do you think it is not a duplicate?

Comment: @FoggyFinder That question just wants a solution that'll work with a *blocking* call to open the window. I need a solution that'll let me continue working in FSI.